# designing for search

Tags: design-patterns, jsp, search

I have jsp form with 10 input selection types. I want to design a search component based on these parameters.

Do I have to put more `if else` conditions based on search criteria?

Can anyone tell me how to design this scenario to avoid `if else` conditions?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, [Query By Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example) is the right way to handle these. ORM frameworks like Hibernate provides this functionality out of the box. May be you have to roll your own using prepared statements, named parameters with JDBC.